# Adjacent faces to a vertex of a vertex of a polytope

Tags: matlab

I am a total newbie in Matlab.
For a given faces of a polytope, how can I collect adjacent faces of a  vertex of a polytope in matlab? 
Example: v = [
-1 0 0 %vertex 1
1 0 0 %vertex 2
1 1 0 %vertex 3
0 1 0 %...
0 0 1
1 0 1
1 1 1
1 1 1
];

% faces are defined by vertex number
f = [
1 2 6 5 %face 1
2 3 7 6 %face 2
3 4 8 7 %face 3
4 1 5 8 %...
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
];
Here, the size of each vectors of 'f' can be different.  How can I collect the adjacent faces of each vertex using matlab.

Answer (score 0):

Try the *patch* function

patch(v, f, 'r'), where v stays for the vector of the vertex, f for the faces, 'r' stays for red